# How to found out when the data is match and display the message

Tags: php

When the customer and product name is match show "yes", if not show "No".

```
shopping cart table
---------------------------
id|product name   | customer
-----------------------------
1 |book           |  Tomic
2 |pencil         |  Tomic
3 |shoe           |  Jasper
-------------------------------


product name| 
--------------------------
book        | add to cart
---------------------------
```

When Tomic(customer) click add to cart show "yes", if Jasper(customer) click add to cart show "No"

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $customer = $_SESSION['login_user'];

    $res2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM shopping_cart where product_name='$product_name'");

    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
    {
        if($customer==$row2['customer'])
        {
            echo "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: `if($customer=='Tomic') {...` ?

Comment: i getting result "yesyes"

Comment: $customer is a account

Comment: you're getting yesyes, because there are two items in the shopping cart with a matching product-name

Comment: but i just want one time only

Comment: to check if you have any result at all use `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($res2);`. Then `if($rowcount && $customer==$row2['customer']) {...`

Comment: send the user with the post (`$user = $_POST['user']`) and change the WHERE clause from query: `WHERE product_name='$product_name' AND customer=$user`. If returns no results, it is `no`, otherwise `yes`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

change your query for `yes` or `no` condition

```
"SELECT * FROM shopping_cart where product_name='$product_name' and customer='$customer'"
```

you can use `mysqli_num_rows();`

```
$data=mysqli_num_rows($res2);
if($data>0){
    echo "yes";
    }
    else{
    echo "no";
    }
```

Comment: But, of course, don't use $customer like that in order to avoid SQL injections.